# Representing multiple HABTM relationships between two models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I'm making a tool to help epicureans keep track of which delicacies they've indulged in and which they haven't. I'm going to have two models, User and Dish.  Each user will need to be able to identify 2) the dishes they WANT to eat but don't
   know how to prepare and 3) the dishes they know hot to prepare and
   want to eat

- 1) the dishes they've eaten
- 2) The dishes they want to eat but don't know how to cook
- 3) The dishes they want to eat and know how to prepare

Additionally, I would like the dish model to be able to identify the users in each of these categories, with respect to the dish.

What is the best practice for establishing what seems here to be multiple has_and_belongs_to_many relationships between two models? In the past I have manually created a join model , such as UsersEatenDishes, to contain foreign keys linking two models, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it.

Thanks in advance for your assistance, and apologies if this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
has_many :through
```

can help you in this situation, with it, you can have more than just ids of models buts also some additional datas

Comment: Yeah, thats the tactic I've used for HABTM before. I don't see anything inherently wrong with using multiple join models here, myself, but its good to get a second opinion. Thanks!